# Open Existing PowerPoint via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm referencing an older post, when trying to figure out how to open an existing pptx, so that I can add a new slide to the deck via VBA. The below link is to the post, however, when I try to run the sub I receive an "Object Required" run-time error after selecting the pptx. I've also included the code that I tried running, based on the associated post. Any idea how to resolve this error?

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687335/user-input-to-select-powerpoint-presentation#:%7E:text=With%20Application.FileDialog%20%28msoFileDialogFilePicker%29.AllowMultiSelect%20%3D%20False%20%27only%20allows%20the,the%20dialog%20box..%20Title%20%3D%20%22Select%20the%20File.%22)

```
Sub Test()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False  'only allows the user to select one file
        ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Select the File."  'Put any text to help the user choose the correct file
        'clear filters then add pptx filter
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "PowerPoint files", "*.pptx"   ' This can be any file extension to filter the choices
        ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
        ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
        ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        fxname = .SelectedItems(1)
      End If
   End With
 Set opres = Presentations.Open(fxname, False, False, True) 'opres is the variable for the choosen file
 opres.Windows(1).Activate  'Activates that presentation.
End Sub
```

When debugging, the `Set opres = Presentations.Open(fxname, False, False, True)` is what's highlighted as an error.

Comment: How is `opres` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the proper reference to open PowerPoint Presentations, open with  createobject, look at [Open a PowerPoint presentation from Excel with VBA and then set that presentation to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594476/open-a-powerpoint-presentation-from-excel-with-vba-and-then-set-that-presentatio)

Comment: Thanks you! The `Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")` resolved the issue.